# Limits of series, proof of the convergence of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I have two sequences $x_i$ and $y_i$ defined by their expressions :
$$x_i-x_{i+1}=y_i-y_{i+1}=\sqrt{x_{i+1}y_{i+1}}$$
I have to prove that $xy(x-y)=0$. I tried this : I have
$$x_i=x^{2^{i-1}}\prod_{j=0}^{j=i-2} (x^{2^j}+y^{2^j})^{-1}$$
And
$$y_i=y^{2^{i-1}}\prod_{j=0}^{j=i-2} (x^{2^j}+y^{2^j})^{-1}$$
How to prove that $x=y$ ?
I tried this : I suppose $x\neq{y}$ and I define the series. I see that 
$$\sqrt{x_iy_i}=y_{i-1}-y_i=x_{i-1}-x_i$$
So
$$x_i-x_{i+1}=\sqrt{x_{i+1}y_{i+1}}$$
$$x_{i-1}-x_i=\sqrt{x_iy_i}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$x_1-x_2=x-x_2=\sqrt{x_2y_2}$$
Or
$$\sum_{j=2}^{j=i+1}{(\sqrt{x_jy_j})}=x-x_2+x_2-x_3+\cdots+x_i-x_{i+1}=x-x_{i+1}$$
Its limit is
$$\sum_{j=2}^{j=\infty}{(\sqrt{x_jy_j})}=\lim_{i\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(x-x_{i+1})}$$
If $x\geq{y}$
$$\sum_{j=2}^{j=\infty}{(\sqrt{x_jy_j})}=\lim_{i\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(x-x_{i+1})}=x-(x-y)=y$$
If $x\leq{y}$
$$\sum_{j=2}^{j=\infty}{(\sqrt{x_jy_j})}=\lim_{i\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(x-x_{i+1})}=x$$
I suppose $x\geq{y}$. Hence
$$\sum_{j=2}^{j=i}{((-1)^j\sqrt{x_jy_j})}=x-x_2-(x_2-x_3)+(x_3-x_4)-\cdots+(-1)^i(x_{i-1}-x_i)$$
  $$=x-2x_2+2x_3-\cdots+2(-1)^{i-1}x_{i-1}+(-1)^{i+1}x_i$$
  $$=2\sum_{j=2}^{j=i-1}{((-1)^{j+1}x_j)}+x+(-1)^{i+1}x_i$$
$$=2\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}{((-1)^{j+1}x_j)}-x-(-1)^{i+1}x_i$$
$$=\sum_{j=2}^{j=i-1}{((-1)^{j+1}x_j)}+\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}{((-1)^{j+1}x_j)}$$
$$=2\sum_{j=2}^{j=i-1}{((-1)^{j+1}y_j)}+y+(-1)^{i+1}y_i$$
$$=2\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}{((-1)^{j+1}y_j)}-y-(-1)^{i+1}y_i$$
$$=\sum_{j=2}^{j=i-1}{((-1)^{j+1}y_j)}+\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}{((-1)^{j+1}y_j)}$$
Or 
  $$2\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}{((-1)^{j+1}x_j)}=\sum_{j=2}^{j=i}{((-1)^j\sqrt{x_jy_j})}+x+(-1)^{i+1}x_i$$
And
$$2\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}{((-1)^{j+1}y_j)}=\sum_{j=2}^{j=i}{((-1)^j\sqrt{x_jy_j})}+y+(-1)^{i+1}y_i$$
I do not know the limit of $(-1)^{i+1}x_i$, 
  $$\sum_{j=1}^{j=\infty}{((-1)^{j}x_j)}$$ may diverge. But
  $$\sum_{j=2}^{j=\infty}{((-1)^j\sqrt{x_jy_j})}$$ is absolutely convergent. As $y_i$ tends to zero in the infinity, then
  $$\sum_{j=1}^{j=\infty}{((-1)^{j}y_j)}$$ converge. The limit of
  $$\sum_{j=2}^{j=i}{((-1)^j\sqrt{x_jy_j})}=2\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}{((-1)^{j+1}y_j)}-y-(-1)^{i+1}y_i$$
  $$=2\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}{((-1)^{j+1}x_j)}-x-(-1)^{i+1}x_i$$
exists and the series are convergent. I will try to prove
that
  $$\lim_{i\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(x_i)}=x-y=0$$
Let
 $$\sum_{k=1}^{k=2m}{((-1)^{k+1}x_{k}e^{-\frac{k}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 $$=xe^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-x_2e^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}+x_3e^{-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2m}}}-\cdots+(-1)^{2m+1}x_{2m}e^{-\frac{2m}{\sqrt{2m}}}$$
 $$=xe^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}+x(e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-e^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}})-x_2e^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}+x_3e^{-\frac{4}{\sqrt{2m}}}+x_3(e^{-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2m}}}-e^{-\frac{4}{\sqrt{2m}}})-x_4e^{-\frac{4}{\sqrt{2m}}}+\cdots-x_{2m}e^{-\frac{2m}{\sqrt{2m}}}$$
 $$=xe^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)+x_3e^{-\frac{4}{\sqrt{2m}}}(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)+\cdots+x_{2m-1}e^{-\frac{2m}{\sqrt{2m}}}(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)+$$
 $$+(x-x_2)e^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}+(x_3-x_4)e^{-\frac{4}{\sqrt{2m}}}+\cdots+(x_{2m-1}-x_{2m})e^{-\frac{2m}{\sqrt{2m}}}$$
 $$=(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)(xe^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}+x_3e^{-\frac{4}{\sqrt{2m}}}+\cdots+x_{2m-1}e^{-\sqrt{2m}})+(\sqrt{x_2y_2}e^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}+\sqrt{x_4y_4}e^{-\frac{4}{\sqrt{2m}}}+\cdots+\sqrt{x_{2m}y_{2m}}e^{-\frac{2m}{\sqrt{2m}}})$$
 $$=(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{2m}}})}+\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(\sqrt{x_{2k}y_{2k}}e^{-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
Also
 $$\sum_{k=1}^{k=2m}{((-1)^{k+1}y_{k}e^{-\frac{k}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 $$=ye^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-y_2e^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}+y_3e^{-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2m}}}-\cdots+(-1)^{2m+1}y_{2m}e^{-\frac{2m}{\sqrt{2m}}}$$
 $$=(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{2m}}})}+\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(\sqrt{x_{2k}y_{2k}}e^{-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 But
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{2m}}})}=S$$
 And
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k+1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}<S<(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)e^{-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2m}}}\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})}<S<(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 Thus
 $$\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)y+(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=2}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}$$
 $$=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=2}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(S)}$$
 And
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2m}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p}{\sqrt{2m}}})}=A$$
 Or
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p+1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}<A<(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 Also
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)e^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}<A<(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 Hence
 $$\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}$$
 $$=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)y_{2p-1}e^{-\frac{p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}}+(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p+1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}$$
 $$=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p+1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(A)}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(S)}$$
 For
 $$p+1=m\Rightarrow{\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(A)}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(S)}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)y_{2m-1}e^{-\frac{m}{\sqrt{2m}}})}=0}$$
 Consequently
 $$\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(y_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=0$$
 Also
  $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{2m}}})}=S$$
 Or
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k+1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}<S<(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)e^{-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2m}}}\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})}<S<(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 And
 $$\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)x+(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=2}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}$$
 $$=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=2}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-2}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(S)}$$
 Or
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2m}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p}{\sqrt{2m}}})}=A$$
 And
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p+1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}<A<(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 Or
 $$(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)e^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2m}}}\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}<A<(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})}$$
 Hence
 $$\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}$$
 $$=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)x_{2p-1}e^{-\frac{p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}}+(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p+1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}$$
 $$=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=p+1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k-p-1}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(A)}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(S)}$$
 For
 $$p+1=m\Rightarrow{\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(A)}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(S)}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)x_{2m-1}e^{-\frac{m}{\sqrt{2m}}})}=0}$$
 Consequently
 $$\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}-1)\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(x_{2k-1}e^{-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=0$$
I deduce
$$0<\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(\sum_{k=1}^{k=2m}{((-1)^{k+1}x_{k}e^{-\frac{k}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}$$
$$=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(\sum_{k=1}^{k=2m}{((-1)^{k+1}y_{k}e^{-\frac{k}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}$$
$$=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(\sqrt{x_{2k}y_{2k}}e^{-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}<\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}{(\sqrt{x_{2k}y_{2k}})})}$$
$$<\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(\sum_{k=1}^{k=2m}{(\sqrt{x_{k}y_{k}})})}=y$$
Thus
$$\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(\sum_{k=1}^{k=2m}{((-1)^{k+1}(x_k-y_k)e^{-\frac{k}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=0$$
$$=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((x-y)\sum_{k=1}^{k=2m}{(e^{-\frac{k}{\sqrt{2m}}})})}=\lim_{m\longrightarrow{\infty}}{((x-y)e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}\frac{1-e^{-\sqrt{2m}}}{1+e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}}})}=\frac{x-y}{2}=0$$
And
$$x-y=0$$
I recapitulate

$$x_i>x_{i+1},\quad{y_i>y_{i+1}}\Rightarrow{x=y}$$

$$x_i=x_{i+1}=x_{i+1}+\sqrt{x_{i+1}y_{i+1}}\Rightarrow{xy=0}$$

$$y_i=y_{i+1}=y_{i+1}+\sqrt{x_{i+1}y_{i+1}}\Rightarrow{xy=0}$$
$$\Rightarrow{xy(x-y)=0}$$
Is this calculus correct ? Thank you.

Comment: Is this the longest question ever on MSE?

Comment: I **cannot** read through this!!!

Comment: On reading the first part, you see that $x_i=y_i$, but with a change of variables. Why do you need $x=y$?

Comment: To prove that $x=y$ in such a sequence is what is requested, here ! Have you an idea ? Is my calculation correct ?

Comment: @JamelG Your question is missing some conditions. For example, maybe the condition is $\lim x_i = \lim y_i < \infty$. In its current form, $x$ and $y$ can be anything.

Comment: The truth is that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are defined from diophantine equations, and we have effectively with some conditions (you can see them in the body of the calculation) that $x=y$... Do you see this ? My question is very long, I tried to put the most important : is my proof correct ?

Comment: This might sound strange but indeed the question is incomplete. There is no way to prove that $x=y$ with the hypotheses written before "How to prove that $x=y$?" (nor, seemingly, with what is written after this, but, for obvious reasons, I only skimmed through this latter part).

Comment: It's a funny thing. Huge question yet no answers. Kind of sad to see so much effort going to waste. :|